# Unable to start the test in JMeter with 1000 users . (I see thread count in negative)

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

Using a controller, I am trying to connect two remote machines to start the test. With low load (example: 50 users) I was able to run all the 5 scripts. My goal is to run with 1000 users. When I do remote start all from the controller, I don't see any traffic or users doing activity. After some time when I stop the test, I see negative number in threads count in upper right corner. Suggest a solution!

Answer (score 1):

Some things you may consider about your question:

- Running 1000 threads with JMeter in one computer it is not a good option as that computer will be the bottle neck and not the application. So you need to manage to run the scripts from more than one computer.
- How many users do you want to simulate? If you want to simulate 1000 real users, I would say that you don´t need to run 1000 threads as they will hit as 10 times these users or more. In any case, if you need 1000 threads you can split that into 5-10 computers or, if you have that, work with cloud resources.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Usually *jmeter.log* file contains all the information you need to get to the bottom of an issue. Check it on both master and slave nodes and take necessary steps to fix it.

Also JMeter default configuration is not suitable for running 1000 threads (or if you have 2 slave machines - 500 threads), you will need at least increase [Java Heap space](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html) option by default only 512Mb are allocated to Java virtual machine which hosts JMeter process.

Locate the following line in JMeter start-up script (`jmeter.bat` or `jmeter` in "bin" folder)

```
HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
```

And change `-Xmx515m` value to be ~80% of your total available physical RAM.

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) for more JMeter performance and tuning tips and tweaks.